# FileWriter isn't writing all of my data

Tags: java, io

So, basically it works, but it doesn't. It doesn't throw any errors, it just doesn't finish writing the file. It does read all of the lines in the file and they are all formatted correctly. I've tried debugging all of that. When debugging the "currentLine" all of the lines show up and are formatted correctly; However if I check my file that I'm writing to, it writes some of them perfectly, and then will just cut off at the end. Like the program didn't have enough time before killing itself.

My guess would be that writing takes awhile, and the program is being terminated before the file finishes writing, if that's the case, how can I avoid that?

Here's the code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Main {

    BufferedReader fileReader;
    BufferedWriter fileWriter;

    private Main() {
        try {
            fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("File/spawn-config.cfg"));
            fileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Dumped/world_npcs.json"));
            loadFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void loadFile() {
        String currentLine;
        try {
            fileWriter.write("[\n");
            while((currentLine = fileReader.readLine()) != null) {
                if(!currentLine.startsWith("//") && !currentLine.startsWith("[")
                        && !currentLine.startsWith("/*")) {
                    System.err.println(currentLine);
                    String[] array = currentLine.split("\\t");
                    String npcID = array[0].substring(7);
                    String xPos = array[1];
                    String yPos = array[2];
                    String zPos = array[3];
                    String walk = "false";
                    String radius = "0";
                    //-----------------------
                    fileWriter.write("{\n");
                    fileWriter.write("\"npc-id\": "+npcID+"\n");
                    fileWriter.write("\"position\": {\n");
                    fileWriter.write("\"x\": " + xPos + "\n");
                    fileWriter.write("\"y\": " + yPos + "\n");
                    fileWriter.write("\"z\": " + zPos + "\n");
                    fileWriter.write("},\n");
                    fileWriter.write("\"walking-policy\": {\n");
                    fileWriter.write("\"coordinate\": false, \"radius\": 0\n");
                    fileWriter.write("}\n},");
                }               
            }

            fileWriter.write("]");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] params) {
        new Main();
    }

}
```

Comment: Close the `BufferedWriter`

Comment: Yeah, you need to close fileWriter after to finish writing the file.

Comment: Oh, well then..
Thanks guys! Worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you are ready with writing flush and close the outputstream

```
 fileWriter.flush();
 fileWriter.close();
```

Comment: I think `fileWriter.close();` calls `flush()` so an explicit call to it is not required.